# Yard: Specify a different path for the compiled doc (instead of doc/)?

Tags: ruby, yard

Is there any way to tell Yard not to clutter up my Rails project's `doc/` folder? I'd like it to save its files in `doc/yard/` or something like that. Sadly I didn't find any option for that.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
yardoc --output-dir /path/to/yard/doc app.rb
```

Comment: Thank you. I was too occupied searching for something "I dont know what" instead of taking a look at `yard -h`...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to conifgure this and forget about it. If so, `.yardopts` in your project root directory is the way to go - you just write the option in the file, one per line, so something like:

```
$ echo --output-dir /path/to/yard/doc >> .yardopts
```

(or use `vi` or whatever to edit the file by hand)

With that in place you can just do

```
$ yard doc
```